# Create a lazy Stream from a Flux

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm trying to create a lazy-`Stream` with Project Reactor in `Californium-SR10`.

According to [the javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#toIterable--):

> Transform this Flux into a lazy Iterable blocking on Iterator.next() calls.

Consequently, I have tried the following:

```
AtomicInteger generatedElements = new AtomicInteger(0);
Flux<Integer> source = Flux
    .range(0, 10)
    .doOnRequest(req -> System.out.println("Requested " + req))
    .doOnRequest(req -> generatedElements.addAndGet((int) req))
    .limitRate(2)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

Iterator<Integer> l = source.toIterable().iterator();
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(0);
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(1);
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(2);

Thread.sleep(2000);
assertThat(generatedElements.get()).isEqualTo(4);
```

Which gives me the following surprising result:

```
Requested 2
Requested 2
Requested 2
Requested 2
Requested 2
Requested 2


org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[4]> but was:<[12]>
Expected :4
Actual   :12
```

Have you any explanation on what happen here (and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why is every parameter passed to `doOnRequest()` 2?

`doOnRequest()` will fire whenever the subscriber requests new elements from upstream (along with the number of elements requested as its parameter.) Since you've limited the rate to 2, you'd expect this to be called with 2 as a parameter every time, which it's doing.

### Why does the `Flux` not complete lazily?

Well, actually it *does*, but not how you expect it to. Lazy doesn't necessarily mean "one at a time", it just means it will evaluate *batches* as they're called for, rather than always evaluating the whole `Flux` in one go.

Specifically, note that the `limitRate()` method *doesn't* apply automatically to the iterator in the same way - it has a *separate* batch size that you have to specify as a parameter to the `toIterable()` method.

You can specify a prefetch rate *and* a batch size of 1, and then you're *likely* to only get 4 elements generated (rather than 3, as it'll always have at least one additional element ready for the following `next()` call):

```
AtomicInteger generatedElements = new AtomicInteger(0);
Flux<Integer> source = Flux
        .range(0, 10)
        .limitRate(1)
        .doOnRequest(req -> System.out.println("Requested " + req))
        .doOnRequest(req -> generatedElements.addAndGet((int) req));

Iterator<Integer> l = source.toIterable(1).iterator();
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(0);
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(1);
assertThat(l.next()).isEqualTo(2);

assertThat(generatedElements.get()).isEqualTo(4);
```

However, note that even this isn't guaranteed in all circumstances, as it just depends on when the backpressure is applied, and when the `Flux` responds to it.